# Facebook API gives Error from Today

Tags: facebook-graph-api

till today my facebook api under PHP worked well.
I did not change anything. But from today on i get the following error:

> facebook failed: "error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure
>   /usr/bin/php /var/www/pas/www/cronjobs/cronjob.channelsActions.php

Has anybody got an idea, how i could solve that error?

Answer (score 11):

It's because of the [POODLE: SSLv3.0 vulnerability (CVE-2014-3566)](https://access.redhat.com/articles/1232123).

After this vulnerability was announced today, many services disabled SSLv3 completely for the time being, including Facebook, and it happens that Facebook uses SSLv3 in their PHP SDK.

I am not sure if you have the same Facebook PHP SDK version as me, but if you have the base_facebook.php file, find the line:

```
$opts[CURLOPT_SSLVERSION] = 3;
```

And change it to a value that does not allow SSLv3 any longer ([find all constants listed](http://php.net/manual/en/curl.constants.php)):

```
$opts[CURLOPT_SSLVERSION] = CURL_SSLVERSION_DEFAULT;
```

or:

```
$opts[CURLOPT_SSLVERSION] = CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1;
```

or:

```
$opts[CURLOPT_SSLVERSION] = CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_0;
```

This way the Facebook API calls will use TLSv1.0 instead of SSLv3.
In my case this line is in the "makeRequest($url, $params, $ch=null)" function at line 963, but depending on the version of the PHP SDK you're using it may differ.

Comment: I replaced “[Facebook] API” with “[Facebook] PHP SDK” where appropriate, because I think that’s what you actually meant. The API and the PHP SDK are different things. Apart from that, +1

Comment: Seems like in Android API there's the same problem

Comment: I would thing that either CURL_SSLVERSION_DEFAULT or CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1 would be a better choice so it negotiates the best version of TLS1.x supported rather than locking in to V1.0 (for the day when we learn of the inevitable V1.0 exploit).

Answer (score 1):

Facebook made the decision to drop support for SSL 3.0 across Facebook properties, including the Facebook Platform API and the Real-Time Updates API, after a serious vulnerability in the protocol was revealed publicly on October 14, 2014 (http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2014/10/this-poodle-bites-exploiting-ssl-30.html). This change helps protect people’s information.

Older versions of our PHP SDK (Facebook PHP SDK 3.1.1 and older) that used SSL 3.0 will no longer work. All developers should upgrade to a version of our SDK that uses TLS - Facebook SDK 3.2.3 or greater. We recommend that developers upgrade to our latest SDK, SDK 4.0.0.

- PHP SDK 3.2.3: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/3.2.3
- PHP SDK 4.0.0: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/4.0.0
- Dev Doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#disable-ssl-v30F

Answer (score 1):

My server has not upgraded to PHP 5.5 or 5.6, the version which includes `CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_0`.

The fix, with older PHP versions, is to comment out the line:

```
$opts[CURLOPT_SSLVERSION$
```