# Programatically creating Test Users with cURL using the Facebook v2.1 Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to programatically create Facebook Test Users for my Facebook App.

I've been looking at the API docs for the HTTP Facebook Graph API v2.1:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/app/accounts/test-users

The section about publishing has led me to believe that I should have adequate permissions to create Test Users programatically with just my app-access-token:

> - An app access token is required to create new test users for that app.

So I've tried forming a request like this:

```
curl -v --data "name=foo&access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/99999999999999/accounts/test-users
```

The access_token I am using is my 'App Token' as shown on this page:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/

It almost works.  A new user `foo` does indeed get created, `foo` even shows up in the Test Users section on the Facebook App Developer page.  However, the request consistently yields a strange response:

```
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< WWW-Authenticate: OAuth "Facebook Platform" "unknown_error" "An unknown error has occurred."
< Facebook-API-Version: v2.1
< ...
{"error":{"message":"An unknown error has occurred.","type":"OAuthException","code":1}}
```

I've taken a look at a number of older posts from users on Stack Overflow with similar problems, however, after trying the suggestions in those threads I still face the same problem, I suspect the suggestions in those threads are specific to older versions of the Facebook Graph API.

Can someone please explain what is going wrong?  Is this something that I should be able to do from cURL without being logged into Facebook myself?

Answer (score 2):

I just tried again with the exact same cURL request (the next day) and got 200 back from Facebook as expected.

There must have been an issue at Facebook's end.  Or their API is super flakey!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the generated token on their page to test this. You need to generate the token yourself using a previous curl request, and then pass that token into your next one.

See [Access Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/) for more information

Comment: What do you mean by `the generated token on their page`?

Comment: You can't use the facebook generated app token for creating test users through curl, you must generate the token in curl yourself.

Answer (score 1):

The app access token can either be one generated by facebook or `app_id|secret`. However, the endpoint seems to be broken since last night at the moment, I just submitted a question wondering if anybody else has had the same issue.

Comment: `"app_id" + "|" + "app_secret"`? Where does it say that in the docs?

Comment: He's correct, that is how you make an app access token.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a fix, but I have some new data.

This started happening to me yesterday 2014-10-14, sometime between 10 AM and 12 PM PDT.  Code and an FB app which had been working previously stopped working, and remains broken today.

Surprisingly, when I look at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/FB_APP_ID/roles/test-users/, I can see the new users.

So the call is "working" in that new users are being created, but it is broken in that we get a 500 code=1 message="An unknown error has occurred."

Comment: Hypothesis: given the timing, perhaps this is related to SSLv3 POODLE issues as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26379077/facebook-api-gives-error-from-today.

Comment: I've tried TLSv1, to no avail.  

I now doubt this hypothesis: if FB were cutting me off due to SSLv3, it would not have created the test users on the back end.

Comment: Found the FB thread where they discuss this bug: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/777357412310228/

They acked the bug was valid, and on their end. It got fixed sometime last night. :)