# Facebook Test User error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use facebook login in my app and have tests for it. I use the /{app-id}/accounts/test-users endpoint to create users for my tests but the endpoint fails with the very generic

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "An unknown error has occurred.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 1
  }
}
```

(which says the API is possibly down). I tried this with 3 different appids/secrets, both with using app_id|app_secret as the token and with a token from the get token endpoint. I also tested this on the Graph Api Explorer and it's giving me the same error. It was working fine but then it suddenly stopped.
What I want to know is 1. is it down? and 2. if not, what did i do wrong or what changed since yesterday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1 this also started to me yesterday mid-morning, with code and an FB app which had been working previously and was unchanged.

When I look at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/FB_APP_ID/roles/test-users/, I can see the new users.

So the call is "working" in that new users are being created, but it is broken in that we get a 500 and we don't get an access_token.

I don't have an answer yet.

Comment: This thread may be a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26386207/programatically-creating-test-users-with-curl-using-the-facebook-v2-1-graph-api

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem last week. After long hours of debugging I found out that I would get this same error every time I tried to create multiple test users with the same name simultaneously (i.e. when running tests in multiple threads).

So instead of setting custom a user name I don't even use the `name` field and I just let Facebook generate one. This way everything works fine. Seriously. I love Facebook API so much. :)

Hope this helps someone.